# The <a> tag throws the alignment off

Tags: html, css

Depending on where I put the `</a>` tag, the boxes look different. Here is what it looks like at the moment.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7mzdL80q/3/)

```
<a href="#">  <div class="box">
  <header><h2>Responsive C3</h2></header>
  <div id="chartA">
  </div>
</div></a>
```

How can I keep the first box as a clickable object while the second box is aligned side by side? With out the `<a></a>` tags then they align just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the class `box` allow your blocks to `float:left` and therefore be side-by-side.
If you apply `class="box"` to the `a` tag instead of the `div` tag it will work as you expect.

```
<a href="#" class="box">  
  <div>
    <header>
      <h2>Responsive C3</h2>
    </header>
    <div id="chartA">
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Here is a good article to understand more about `float` : https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ and another about `display`: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly.